# What does "agreements between groups of countries" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Administrative procedures relating to border crossings whether they fall within the competence of States or result from international agreements, such as visas or health and customs formalities, should be adapted, so far as possible, so as to facilitate to the maximum freedom of travel and widespread access to international tourism; **agreements between groups of countries** to harmonize and simplify these procedures should be encouraged ([Source](http://ethics.unwto.org/en/content/full-text-global-code-ethics-tourism))

*Groups of countries* means for example northern European countries and western European countries? I mean there are different groups out there and agreement should be reached between say Group A and Group B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase is asking that countries in Group A reach an agreement about this topic and that separately the countries in Group B reach an agreement about the same topic. The two groups may have different agreements. The goal is that tourism (etc) is as easy as possible for people in the Group A countries to visit other Group A countries. Similarly for people in Group B countries  to visit other Group B countries. (... and groups C and D etc)

The text is not desiring that the countries in Group A agree with those in Group B.

The plurality on "groups" is desiring that a number of agreements be created, one per group of countries. Not that one agreement be created that covers several groups of countries.

As an example. France and the UK are members of a group that has an agreement so that UK people can easily visit France and vice versa. Separately the USA and Canada are members of a group were USA people can easily visit Canada and vice versa. However French and UK people need to get a visa to visit either the USA or Canada, and vice versa.